# Run command on Minikube startup

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

I'm using Minikube for working with Kubernetes on my local machine, and would like to run a command on the VM just after startup (preferably before the Pods start). I can run it manually with `minikube ssh`, but that's a bit of a pain to do after every restart, and is difficult to wrap in a script.

Is there an easy way to do this?

The command in my case is this, so that paths on the VM match paths on my host machine:

```
sudo mount --bind /hosthome/<user> /home/<user>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe flags which can you pass to `minikube start` would be useful in your case:

```
  --mount                          This will start the mount daemon and automatically mount files into minikube
  --mount-string string            The argument to pass the minikube mount command on start (default "/home/user:/minikube-host")
```

Edit:
Maybe you could write script for starting your minikube like:

```
minikube start && ssh -t -i ~/.minikube/machines/minikube/id_rsa docker@$(minikube ip) "sudo mount --bind /hosthome/<user> /home/<user>"
```

that will start minikube and issue bind command using SSH after start

Comment: That's what I've used before, but ran into lots of issues with the 9p filesystem used for the `--mount` options, which I don't get when using the Virtualbox mounts used for the `/hosthome` folder.

Comment: I've tried some ideas but it seems there is no better way than achieving what you want with minikube other than @Jakub provided.

Comment: @Ralf I added to answer something what would be useful in your case

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work. Did not know about the ssh key, which is easier to automate than password-based ssh login.

Answer (score 2):

If you need a command run on every start/stop of minikube, you can put it in the script /var/lib/boot2docker/bootlocal.sh which will run on every VM start and is persisted.
So, in order to put your command in bootlocal.sh, run from your host machine:

```
minikube ssh 'echo "sudo mount --bind /hosthome/<user> /home/<user>" | sudo tee -a /var/lib/boot2docker/bootlocal.sh'
```