# How to attach a new hard disk to Minikube in Virtualbox?

Tags: virtualbox, minikube

I'm trying to attach a hard disk to Minikube. I can create a new hard drive by going to settings > storage and adding a new hard disk from there but I don't know how to attach it to Minikube. Anyone know how? any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Giving additional storage for your `minikube` instance can be done in multiple ways within Virtualbox environment.

Some of them are:

- **Create an additional Virtualbox disk and mount it to `minikube` instance**
- Mount `Users` host directory to `minikube` instance **(done by default)**:

  - *[Kubernetes.io: Learning environment: Minikube: Mounted host folders](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/learning-environment/minikube/#mounted-host-folders)*
- Use `$ minikube mount ABSOLUTE_HOST_PATH:ABSOLUTE_MINIKUBE_PATH`

---

Focusing on:

### Create an additional Virtualbox disk and mount it to `minikube` instance

Assuming that:

- You have your `minikube` instance up and running with Virtualbox as a driver
- You attached your newly created disk to your minikube instance (`VMDK` for example)

Steps:

- Check if `minikube` instance is aware of new disk
- Prepare your new disk to be mounted
- Mount your disk
- Use your newly created disk with example pods

---

#### Check if `minikube` instance is aware of new disk

You will need to connect to your `minikube` instance either with:

- run in `powershell`/`cmd`/`terminal` following command:

  - `$ minikube ssh`
- graphically with Virtualbox

You will need to identify the disk you've mounted earlier. You can do it with below command:

- `$ fdisk -l`

Output of this command should look like that:

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 16 GiB, 17179869184 bytes, 33554432 sectors
Disk model: VBOX HARDDISK
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0xb925daf0
```

---

#### Prepare your new disk to be mounted

You will need to create a partition table for this disk and format it.

- `$ fdisk /dev/sdb`
- `n,p,1,enter,enter` - create a one partition for whole disk

You can use below guide for more reference:

- *[Tecmint.com: Add new disk to existing linux server](https://www.tecmint.com/add-new-disk-to-an-existing-linux/)*

You will also need to format this disk:

- `mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb1` # please notice the number

---

#### Mount your disk

You can mount this disk with following commands:

- `mkdir /data/disk` - create a folder to mount your disk into
- `mount /dev/sdb1 /data/disk` - mount your disk to specified location (not working after reboot)

> Disclaimer!
>
> Creating an entry in `/etc/fstab` to have this disk mounted between shutdowns/reboots will not work as `/etc/fstab` will be overridden with each `$ minikube start`

To overcome `/etc/fstab` being overridden you will need to:

- create a file in: `/var/lib/boot2docker/`
- name of: `bootlocal.sh`
- with content: `mount /dev/sdb1 /data/disk`

This steps will create a script that will be executed on each start of your `minikube` instance mounting your disk to a `/data/disk`.

Reference to startup commands in `minikube`:

- *[Stackoverflow.com: Answer: Run command on Minikube startup](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54417037/12257134)*

---

#### Use your newly created disk with example pods

By default `minikube` instance support `hostPath`:

- *[Minikube.sigs.k8s.io: Docs: Handbook: Persistent Volumes](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/persistent_volumes/)*

You can create a PV and PVC with below example:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv0001
spec:
  storageClassName: standard
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  capacity:
    storage: 1Gi
  hostPath:
    path: /data/disk/pv0001
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: pv0001-claim
spec:
  storageClassName: standard
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
  volumeName: pv0001
```

You can mount previously created PVC to a pod:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: ubuntu
spec:
  volumes:
    - name: storage-name
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: pv0001-claim
  containers:
    - name: ubuntu
      image: ubuntu
      command: 
      - sleep
      - "infinity"
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/storage"
          name: storage-name
```

I put a file in `/data/disk/pv0001` to check if it's working:

```sh
$ kubectl exec -it ubuntu -- cat /storage/hello.txt
Hello there!
```